# Analysis of model input resolution

Tags: sample, model, quantiles

I am using a fine resolution soil dataset to run a climate model, and want to explore the impact of aggregating the soil properties at different resolutions on model output. E.g. how do the results differ if we average the soil properties to 1 value per county/state versus 100 different values per county/state.

To this end, I computed the value of the soil property at different percentiles (1st, 2nd...100th), and plan to run the model for multiple selection of percentiles. E.g, once for all 100 percentile values, another time for every 5th percentile value...

Is there a better way to sample though? Could I be missing something by only sampling using this percentile scheme?

Comment: You could consider adding other relevant tags to your question.